# GCP VM instance schedule randomly not starting VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, scheduling, windows-server-2012-r2

We've started using [GCP Instance schedule](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop) for one of our VMs which needs to be up for 3 hours every night. For some reason, about once per week the VM is not up - services can't access it.

Checking from Logs Explorer, there are no errors or warnings, but on those days when it is not working, there are a few events which are not published/logged. These are the **GCE Agent Started** and **OSConfig Agent Started** events which happen on days where everything is OK (09-11, 09-12, 09-14) but are missing on days when the instance is not up (09-13).

The VM is Windows Server 2012 R2.

There is no retry policy implemented in the GCP instance schedule feature.
We know there are other ways to schedule VMs but we'd prefer to use the instance schedule feature if possible and if it is stable.

Is there somewhere else we should look for understanding why the VM is not starting properly?

This is the image from logs:
[image: Logs Explorer]

Answer (score 2):

Instance schedules do not provide capacity guarantees, so if the resources required for a scheduled VM instance are not available at the scheduled time, your VM instance might not start when scheduled. Although you can [reserve VM instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reserving-zonal-resources) before starting them to provide capacity guarantees, **reservations cannot be automatically scheduled**.(Assuming that randomly VM instances are showing up this behaviour every week, not a particular VM every week.)

If it's with the same VM everytime then high memory utilization can also cause VM not being responsive. Manual **reboot** would fix this since it would close whatever is consuming the memory and re-open processes or services that may have been killed due to being OOM.

Please consider monitoring the VM memory usage by installing a [monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/monitoring/installation#agent-install-windows), and increase the memory request based on the utilization.